# RDS (MySQL): Swap usage growing but plenty of freeable memory?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, memory

We run a db.m4.10xlarge instance on Amazon's RDS. It runs 3 fairly busy databases and has a replica instance connected to it.

Over the last few weeks I noticed the swap usage has been steadily rising from 0 to about 80MB now. I don't know why it's using the swap space at all when there's plenty of free (freeable?) RAM. I've included charts from the last 2 weeks below:

[image: Charts from Amazon's RDS service]

The same thing is happening on the replica also, which is another concern of mine as our replica lag is continuing to grow in a similar manner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swap Usage but high Freeable memory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/275763/swap-usage-but-high-freeable-memory)

Comment: [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/420778/why-swap-is-used-when-plenty-of-free-memory-is-left) might be useful.